# Rewrite correlated subquery to CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, correlated-subquery, cross-apply

So I am trying to use `CROSS APPLY` but can't seem to get it rigth.

I have some queries that look like this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM dbo.tableA AS A
WHERE COL3 = (SELECT MAX(COL4)
              FROM dbo.tableA AS B
              WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1) AS SUB
```

The I try this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM dbo.tableA AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(COL4) AS MAX_DATE
              FROM TABLEA AS B
              WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1) AS SUB
```

But I always return more rows when I use the `CROSS APPLY`. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `WHERE` in your second query, if you want the 2 queries to work the same:

```sql
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM dbo.tableA AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(COL4) AS MAX_DATE
              FROM TABLEA AS B
              WHERE A.COL1 = B.COL1) AS SUB 
WHERE A.COL3 = SUB.MAX_DATE;
```

Comment: Thanks, well of course :-). Does it help to put the subquery in a table-valued-function performance wise. I have a POC index on the table. Or will the function only help to make the code more readable? PS it says I have to wait before I can accept.

Comment: It's unlikely to make a different, if I am honest, but you could find out by testing easily enough.

Comment: I still see a bit few more rows for the CROSS APPLY version. Can you explian this?

Comment: Nope, @xhr489 , I have no sample data or expected results. The above *should* be the same so I suspect there's nothing else at hand here.

Comment: Probably won't make any difference, however you need to `set statistics time on` and compare **logical reads** Go with what gives the least, or if the same doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the `APPLY` rewrite, because this is a self-join it can also be done with a `MAX` window aggregate:

```sql
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        MAX(COL4) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1) AS mx
    FROM dbo.tableA
) AS A
WHERE COL3 = mx
```

Comment: Thanks, can you quess why the two version give slightly different results?

Comment: Without sample data, no. Is the query you posted the **full** thing?

Comment: No the outer query has extra predicates in the where clause

Comment: I have figured out why, something I had missed :-)